# Does Anything Reset Casual MMR?

Tags: hearthstone

Is Casual MMR reset for any reason in Hearthstone?

For example, do any of these have an effect on my MMR?

- Character changes
- End of month
- A long break from play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the beta of Hearthstone Aratil a "blue" (customer service rep) on the Battle.net forums indicated that while ranked play MMR reset with each season casual MMR did not.

Unfortunately, Blizzard has closed the beta forums, but the [Blue Tracker at Hearthpwn captured the question and answer](http://www.hearthpwn.com/blue-tracker/topic/4644-ranks-reset-elo-mmr-stays-the-same-is-this-working). To my knowledge there have been no further updates on how MMR works from Blizzard.

Answer (score 2):

Casual MMR does not reset.

[***SOURCE***](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Matchmaking)